How to upload changes without syncing to QFieldCloud from the computer
I am developing a project in QField involving about 10 users who use it from tablets or mobile phones. We all work on the same project, and I have configured automatic upload of changes every 30 minutes. I am paying for the "Organization" subscription, but I have a problem: Several technicians want to work from QGIS (i.e., from a computer), but I can't find a way to sync the information to QFieldCloud from QGIS without replacing the information uploaded by the 10 technicians. Is there any way to upload only the changes made from the computer to QFieldCloud without replacing the entire layer?

If your desktop (QGIS) users only work on the data (and do not change project stuff like layer styling, attribute forms etc.) consider moving your data into a Postgres database. The QGIS users will have a "live sync" with the other QGIS users - QField users download the updated database in the morning, go out and collect data, and upload their data to the database in the evening. (Or, if they have stable internet connection in the field, they could also work "Live" on the database)
